# No implementation of method: :take! of protocol: #'clojure.core.async.impl.protocols/ReadPort found for class: clojure.core.async$chan

Tags: clojure

I'm learning [clojure.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) library.

Below is my code.

```clj
(ns channels.create
  (:require [clojure.core.async :refer [ chan >!! <!!]]))

(let [c chan]
  (future (>!! c 42))
  (future (println (<!! c))))
```

When I send the above namespace to repl I get below error -

> #object[clojure.core$future_call$reify__8544
> 0x3cf627ec
> {:status :failed,
> :val #error{:cause "No implementation of method: :take! of protocol: #'clojure.core.async.impl.protocols/ReadPort found for class: clojure.core.async$chan",
> :via [{:type java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException,
> :message "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :take! of protocol: #'clojure.core.async.impl.protocols/ReadPort found for class: clojure.core.async$chan",
> :at [java.util.concurrent.FutureTask report "FutureTask.java" 122]}
> {:type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,
> :message "No implementation of method: :take! of protocol: #'clojure.core.async.impl.protocols/ReadPort found for class: clojure.core.async$chan",
> :at [clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn invokeStatic "core_deftype.clj" 584]}],
> :trace [[clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn invokeStatic "core_deftype.clj" 584]
> [clojure.core$_cache_protocol_fn invoke "core_deftype.clj" 576]
> [clojure.core.async.impl.protocols$eval1957$fn__1958$G__1948__1965
> invoke
> "protocols.clj"
> 15]
> [clojure.core.async$fn__2637 invokeStatic "async.clj" 135]
> [clojure.core.async$fn__2637 invoke "async.clj" 127]
> [channels.create$eval11241$fn__11244 invoke "create.clj" 3]
> [clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__5823 invoke "core.clj" 2047]
> [clojure.lang.AFn call "AFn.java" 18]
> [java.util.concurrent.FutureTask run$$$capture "FutureTask.java" 264]
> [java.util.concurrent.FutureTask run "FutureTask.java" -1]
> [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor runWorker "ThreadPoolExecutor.java" 1128]
> [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker run "ThreadPoolExecutor.java" 628]
> [java.lang.Thread run "Thread.java" 829]]}}]

What is the error in my code? How can I fix this error?

Note: The error doesn't happens always but happens consitently 1 out of 4 times.Below is the screenshot.

[image: channel put and take error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chan` is a function. `(chan)` is a channel.

Regarding your "inconsistency" edit: multithreaded code is racy. The REPL sometimes manages to look at the future before it's been evaluated enough to notice the error, and sometimes it doesn't.